# Append parent in results of recursive javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, search, recursion

How am i able to get the parent(s) in the (reverse) tree in the results.

```
var json = '[{"title":"Category1","children":[{"title":"sometitle","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"Subcategory1","children":[{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"}]},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"Subcategory2","children":[{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"}]}]},{"title":"Category2","children":[{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"Subcategory1","children":[{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"}]},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"Subcategory2","children":[{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"}]}]},{"title":"Category3","children":[{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"Subcategory1","children":[{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"}]},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"Subcategory2","children":[{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"}]}]},{"title":"Category4","children":[{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"Subcategory1","children":[{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"}]},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"Subcategory2","children":[{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"},{"title":"video","url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI","thumb":"*.jpg"}]}]}]';

var result = find('sometitle',json);
console.log(result);

function find(needle, arr){
    var results = [];
    for(var k in arr){
        //recursive case
        if(typeof arr[k] === 'object'){
           results = results.concat(find(needle, arr[k]));
        }

        //base case
        if(arr[k]==needle){
            return arr;
        }
    }

    //base case
    return results;
}
```

I tried the following but that will deliver me more than 10** results(objects),

```
//recursive case
if(typeof arr[k] === 'object'){
   results = results.concat(arr[k]);
   results = results.concat(find(needle, arr[k]));
}
```

***Edit:***

**Current result:**

```
0: Object
thumb: "*.jpg"
title: "sometitle"
url: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI"
```

**Expected result:**
For example:

```
   0: Object
     title: "Category1"
      children: Array[1]
        0: Object
```

Thanks,
Jacob

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Could you post 1) source data (`jsonstring`) 2) expected results?

Comment: Why the `concat`? Just go for `return find(needle, arr[k]);`. Also, iterate through in array using `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { [...] }`.

Comment: If you're declaring a variable with JavaScript object literal syntax, there's no need to invoke a JSON parser. Also, don't use `for ... in` loops for arrays.  Also declare "results" with `var`!

Comment: Thanks for the coding suggestions, always a good practice, i added the json string and expected result. Bit of a bad notation sry..about that

Answer (score 0):

Such queries with DefiantJS (defiantjs.com) are trivial. This lib extends the global object JSON with the method "search". Using this method, you can make queries on JSON structures with XPath expressions.

Here is the fiddle for the code below
http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/cPRd9/

Like this (I've shortened your JSON to facilitate overview):

```
    var data = [
       {
          "title": "Category1",
          "children": [
             { "title": "video 1", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" },
             {
                "title": "Subcategory1",
                "children": [
                   { "title": "video 2", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" },
                   { "title": "video 3", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" },
                   { "title": "video 4", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" }
                ]
             },
             { "title": "video 5", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" },
             {
                "title": "Subcategory2",
                "children": [
                   { "title": "video 5", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" },
                   { "title": "video 6", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" },
                   { "title": "video 7", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" }
                ]
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "title": "Category3",
          "children": [
             { "title": "video 8", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" },
             {
                "title": "Subcategory1",
                "children": [
                   { "title": "video 9", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" },
                   { "title": "video 10", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" },
                   { "title": "video 11", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" }
                ]
             },
             { "title": "video 12", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" },
             {
                "title": "Subcategory2",
                "children": [
                   { "title": "video 13", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" },
                   { "title": "video 14", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" },
                   { "title": "video 15", "url": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", "thumb": "*.jpg" }
                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    ],
    res1 = JSON.search( data, '//*[title and url]' ),
    res2 = JSON.search( data, '//*[title = "video 13"]' ),
    str = '';

for (var i=0; i<res1.length; i++) {
    str += res1[i].title +'<br/>';
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str;

console.log( res2[0] );
// {title: "video 13", url: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk5_1OZ4DVI", thumb: "*.jpg"}
```